# iOS Simulator for Xcode 4.5 not copying Resources over

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I am using Xcode 4.5 and iOS Simulator Version 6*. I added images to my Xcode project but when I simulate the iPhone, they are not showing up. I see the following in syslog:

```
SpringBoard[33587] <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Aug 23 15:04:18 new-host-22.home SpringBoard[28968] <Warning>: No file exists for default image of name starting_image_i5_retina
Aug 23 15:04:20 new-host-22.home[28982] <Notice>: BUG in libdispatch: 12E55 - 866 - 0x2
Aug 23 15:04:20 new-host-22.home[28982] <Notice>: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_VNODE] add: "Bad file
```

No idea what is happening. I have tried deleting the app, clean builds, etc.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Xcode 5 which is under NDA (please use the Apple forum)

Comment: sorry - it happens in xCode 4 also - just confirmed

Comment: When and where are you drawing into a context? Have you checked your images are copied into the bundle?

Comment: So it worked before and it stopped working now? how are you loading the images?

Comment: are you sure you have you got both 1x and 2x images in your project?

Answer (score 2):

Go to build phases under your target and go to "copy Bundle Resources" and click the plus button and add the file, clean your build, delete the app, and run it in xcode and the file should be there.